# Completely remove RLMObject in Realm.io

Tags: swift, realm

I see there are ways to empty an RLMObject, but I want to completely remove it from the RLMRealm storage. And I don't want to do a migration either, I want it removed. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way is to do realm.deleteAllObjects on your instance of the realm. More about that here http://realm.io/docs/cocoa/0.90.6/#deleting-objects. This removes all of your objects.

If you want to remove one object, you can do realm.deleteObject(*object here*). There is more on that in the link above as well.

Removing the file like you are doing does prevent the need for migrations, just don't forget to remove that line if you do go that route!

Answer (score 0):

Did it the hard way. Used RLMRealm.defaultRealmPath() to give me the default path. You can use NSFileManager to remove that, and other Realm related files in that directory, or you can do it manually. This will clear ALL the objects.